# Regular expression to extract certain columns from SQL "CREATE TABLE" statements

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

Let's say I have a MySQL dump which creates a lot of tables.

**Example:**

```
CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `REVTYPE` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL
  `some_other_column` varchar(255)
);
```

What whould be a valid regular expression to find the following:

- All lines which start with "CREATE TABLE" and which contains "my_" in the table name
- Then extracting the line containing "tinyint"

So the result would look like:

```
CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
  `REVTYPE` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex seems to work:

```
^((CREATE.*my_.*\n)|(\s+.*tinyint.*\n)|(\s+.*(?!tinyint)\n))


CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `id` bigint(22) NOT NULL,
  `REVTYPE` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `REVTYPE` tinyint(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `some_other_column` varchar(255)
);
```

becomes (replace with `$2$3`) :

```
CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
  `REVTYPE` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `REVTYPE` tinyint(5) DEFAULT NULL,
);
```

[I assume the OP wants the `);` at the end -advise if not true.]
.
See [regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/jm9S3L/):

Comment: This: '[^tinyint.*]' creates a character Group not containing the characters, it does not match a Word.

Comment: Thanks Poul, I was lazy at the coffeeshop - I changed it to a negative lookahead.  Odd that it worked so well as it was...

Comment: This will also match `your_table`.

Comment: Fixed that easily enough.  What I don't know how to do is how to make the 3rd and 4th groups conditional on finding a matching second group?  I.e., stop trying to match (the tinyints) if there is no my_table.  So result would be no matches at all.  I know there are conditional groups but doubt they are supported in vscode.